# access denied in copying batch file

Tags: batch-file, boot, xcopy

Im trying to write a batch file that copy itself to startup folder, so the file will be executed each restart.
Im using this command, but I keep getting "access denied":

```
@echo off
XCOPY txt.txt "C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\StartMenu\Programs\Startup" /y /c /h /o /b
```

When I try to move the file manually, i need to click on a "Continue" button, so I guess I cannot access to the destination.
How can i access to the folder and copy the file?

Thank!

Comment: you should contact an administrator to get permission.

Comment: I'm going to guess that the problem lies in the %username% var. If you change that to your username, does the file copy? Sounds like it could be an environmental variable issue. Which user is running the script? On start up, this would be a system account, correct? That account doesn't have a folder in C:\Users\.. etc.

Comment: Try removing /o, which copies ownership.